# Problems with the of operator of rxjs

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, subscription

I have a complex scenario where I need several observable to get some data.

I have a method like the following:

```js
  private collectData(): Observable<any> {
    const defaultValues = {
      prop3: 'textsdfsdf',
      prop4: 122323,
    };
    let result: Observable<any>;
    if (this.withDialog) {
      result = this._dialog.open(MyDialogComponent).afterClosed();
    } else {
      result = of({});
    }

    return result.pipe(map((next) => ({ ...next, ...defaultValues })));
  }
```

This method returns an observable with some kind of data. Some of the data can be entered in a dialog. But entering the data is optional so if this is not wanted only some default data will be returned to the subscriptors.

This method is called by a different method which will for example add some more data or communicates with the backend and it looks like this:

```js
  private doSth(): Observable<any> {
    const sub = new Subject<any>();
    const data = this.collectData();

    data.subscribe((next) => {
      // Get some data from the backend or do some other stuff
      console.log(['Collected data', next]);
      const newData = {...next, anotherProp: true};
      sub.next(newData);
    });

    return sub.asObservable();
  }
```

This method should return the data and all other stuff also by using a Observable and is called by a third method:

```
  public click() {
    this.doSth().subscribe((next) => {
      console.log(['Got some data', next]);
    });
  }
```

And here is the problem. As long as I use the dialog everything works fine. But when I don't use the dialog and therefor not the `afterClosed()` observable but instead the `of({})` observable the last subscribe never gets the data.

You can find the full example here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-qcayhz?file=src%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of do chaining observables by emiting values from subscription handler, just use `pipe`

If you are going to use another observable (eg http call) to mutate original result in `doSth()` you will then use `switchMap` instead of map etc.

```
  public click() {
    this.doSth().subscribe((next) => {
      console.log(`Got some data. With dialog? ${this.withDialog}`, next);
    });
  }

  private doSth(): Observable<any> {
    return this.collectData().pipe(
      map(next=>({ ...next, anotherProp: true }))
    )
  }

  private collectData(): Observable<any> {
    const defaultValues = {
      prop3: 'defaultProp3',
      prop4: 9999999999,
    };
    const  result= this.withDialog ? this._dialog.open(MyDialogComponent).afterClosed() : of({});
    return result.pipe(map((next) => ({  ...defaultValues,...next })));
  }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-1vd2z5?file=src%2Fapp.component.ts

moreover you are covering actual data with default values, while you should do the other way around, therefore it should be

```
 return result.pipe(map((next) => ({  ...defaultValues,...next })));
```

not the other way around

example output:

```
Got some data. With dialog? true

{prop3: "defaultProp3", prop4: 9999999999, prop1: "text", prop2: 123, …}

Got some data. With dialog? false

{prop3: "defaultProp3", prop4: 9999999999, anotherProp: true}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your subscription to `doSth()` doesn't emit when the "of" case is hit is because of emits synchronously, whereas your dialog case emits asynchronously.

In the following code:

```js
1   private doSth(): Observable<any> {
2     const sub = new Subject<any>();
3     
4     this.collectData().subscribe((next) => {
5       const newData = { ...next, anotherProp: true };
6       sub.next(newData);
7     });
8 
9     return sub.asObservable();
10  }
```

In the sync case, line 2 creates the subject, line 6 emits the value immediately, then line 9 returns the subject.  However, a subscription to a Subject will only emit future values. Since the emissions already happened before the subject was returned (*and subscribed to*), that prior emission is "lost".

In the async case, line 2 creates the subject, line 9 returns the subject, and later on (*after the user dismisses the dialog*) line 6 emits the value.  This sequence allows your subscription to receive the value.

---

There are a few ways to fix this:

You could (*not the best solution, but it would work*) use `timer` instead of `of` to force the emission to be async:

```js
result = timer().pipe(map(() => ({}))
```

Another way would be to use `ReplaySubject(1)` instead of plain `Subject`.  A ReplaySubject will emit the specified number of prior emissions upon subscription, so you don't miss out on the prior emission:

```js
1   private doSth(): Observable<any> {
2     const sub = new ReplaySubject<any>(1);
3     
4     this.collectData().subscribe((next) => {
5       const newData = { ...next, anotherProp: true };
6       sub.next(newData);
7     });
8 
9     return sub.asObservable();
10  }
```

However, you don't actually need any subject at all, just return the observable directly!

```js
private doSth(): Observable<any> {
  return this.collectData().pipe(
    map(next => ({ ...next, anotherProp: true })
  );
}
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-76962827?devtoolsHeight=60&file=src%2Fapp.component.ts)